# Parsing JSON output for Discord Bot in Python

Tags: python, json, discord

**Summary**
I'm currently getting the first object of a JSON array dumping into Discord but I only want a portion of the data, specifically `teams`. I believe I need to edit line 50 `return(odds_json['data'][0])`, can anyone help me with pulling this specific piece of data?

Here's said dump:

> {'id': '19c709db17e33a20f7c88af1a119cef1', 'sport_key': 'basketball_nba', 'sport_nice': 'NBA', 'teams': ['Atlanta Hawks', 'New York Knicks'], 'commence_time': 1622394647, 'home_team': 'Atlanta Hawks', 'sites': [{'site_key': 'fanduel', 'site_nice': 'FanDuel', 'last_update': 1622399415, 'odds': {'h2h': [-1350, 700]}}, {'site_key': 'betmgm', 'site_nice': 'BetMGM', 'last_update': 1622399373, 'odds': {'h2h': [-650, 475]}}, {'site_key': 'betrivers', 'site_nice': 'BetRivers', 'last_update': 1622399389, 'odds': {'h2h': [-910, 540]}}, {'site_key': 'draftkings', 'site_nice': 'DraftKings', 'last_update': 1622399388, 'odds': {'h2h': [-835, 525]}}, {'site_key': 'sugarhouse', 'site_nice': 'SugarHouse', 'last_update': 1622399399, 'odds': {'h2h': [-1000, 575]}}, {'site_key': 'barstool', 'site_nice': 'Barstool Sportsbook', 'last_update': 1622399403, 'odds': {'h2h': [-1000, 575]}}, {'site_key': 'unibet', 'site_nice': 'Unibet', 'last_update': 1622399400, 'odds': {'h2h': [-1000, 575]}}, {'site_key': 'betfair', 'site_nice': 'Betfair', 'last_update': 1622399405, 'odds': {'h2h': [-500, 470], 'h2h_lay': [-476, 500]}}, {'site_key': 'pointsbetus', 'site_nice': 'PointsBet (US)', 'last_update': 1622399407, 'odds': {'h2h': [-620, 410]}}, {'site_key': 'williamhill_us', 'site_nice': 'William Hill (US)', 'last_update': 1622399389, 'odds': {'h2h': [-650, 450]}}, {'site_key': 'foxbet', 'site_nice': 'FOX Bet', 'last_update': 1622399401, 'odds': {'h2h': [-909, 450]}}, {'site_key': 'gtbets', 'site_nice': 'GTbets', 'last_update': 1622399392, 'odds': {'h2h': [-946, 543]}}, {'site_key': 'caesars', 'site_nice': 'Caesars', 'last_update': 1622399398, 'odds': {'h2h': [-455, 320]}}, {'site_key': 'bovada', 'site_nice': 'Bovada', 'last_update': 1622399102, 'odds': {'h2h': [120, -160]}}, {'site_key': 'mybookieag', 'site_nice': 'MyBookie.ag', 'last_update': 1622399393, 'odds': {'h2h': [-285, 210]}}], 'sites_count': 15}

And here's the .py file.

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json

api_key = os.environ['API_KEY']

client = discord.Client()

def get_odds():
  sports_response = requests.get('https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/sports', params={
      'api_key': api_key
  })

  sports_json = json.loads(sports_response.text)

  if not sports_json['success']:
      print(
          'There was a problem with the sports request:',
          sports_json['msg']
      )

  else:
    print('Keep it 200')

  sport_key = 'basketball_nba'

  odds_response = requests.get('https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds', params={
      'api_key': api_key,
      'sport': sport_key,
      'region': 'us', # uk | us | eu | au
      'mkt': 'h2h', # h2h | spreads | totals
      'oddsFormat': 'american'
  })

  odds_json = json.loads(odds_response.text)
  if not odds_json['success']:
      print(
          'There was a problem with the odds request:',
          odds_json['msg']
      )

  else:
      # odds_json['data'] contains a list of live and 
      #   upcoming events and odds for different bookmakers.
      # Events are ordered by start time (live events are first)
      print(
          'Successfully found {} events'.format(len(odds_json['data']))
      )
      return(odds_json['data'][0])

      # Check your usage
      print('Remaining requests', odds_response.headers['x-requests-remaining'])
      print('Used requests', odds_response.headers['x-requests-used'])

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$odds'):
        odds = get_odds()
        await message.channel.send(odds)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: You can delete your question then undelete it once you're ready

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @snakeowens, welcome to SO, could you please state an example what part you need and any code example if you have already tried in this aspect

Comment: I just updated the question with the code and example, sorry I had trouble posting originally.

Comment: @wjandrea, had to leave it posted to be able to edit it or wait 90 mins to repost a new q, so I just live edited!

Comment: @snakeowens OK, now, what's your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that `sports_json['teams']` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds response object contains a list of events. You're currently only returning the first one with `return(odds_json['data'][0])`. (The index 0 is giving you just the first element of the list.)

If you wanted to print all of the teams, you could loop over the events and get each matchup like this:

```
for event in odds_json['data']:
    print(event["teams"])
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! This is getting me in the right direction. I now get the teams but still only for the first event when I'm using `return(event["teams"])`. When I use print, I do see all the events in the interpreter, so it's working, I just gotta get it to play nice with Discord now. Thanks again!

Comment: @snakeowens You're welcome. If you need to return all of the teams, then you'll want to add them to another list (or other data structure) and return that. It just depends on what you want to do with them next. Good luck!